# How to get all attributes of an object including those which are nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I need to get all attributes of an object. I know there's a method `attributes`, but it doesn't return attributes which are nil.
For example:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :email
  field :age
end

u = User.new(email: 'foo@bar.com', name: 'foo')
u.save
u.attributes # {'email' => 'foo@bar.com', 'name' => 'foo'}
```

I need `u.attributes` to return `{'email' => 'foo@bar.com', 'name' => 'foo' 'age' => nil}`

There's a method `as_json` which does what I want, but it's a lot slower. Speed is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick solution

```
self.attribute_names.map { |name| [name, self[name]] }.to_h
```

It does all I want =)